# How to turn an existing list into a key-value pair for a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have two lists, for example:

```
cats = ["Mary", "Snuggles", "Susan"]
rabbits = ["Cottonball", "Snowflake", "Fluffy"]
```

I want to create dictionary animals, where "cats" and "rabbits" are the keys, and their corresponding lists are their values, like:

```
{cats : "Mary", "Snuggles", "Susan"
rabbits : "Cottonball", "Snowflake", "Fluffy"}
```

How can I go about doing this? I also want to make sure that I can add more names to the lists, and more keys to the dictionary later.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Do you know how to define a dictionary?

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid Python dictionary.

Comment: it should look like this `{cats : ["Mary", "Snuggles", "Susan"]
rabbits :[ "Cottonball", "Snowflake", "Fluffy"]}`

Comment: Yes, I have tried to do
    pet_dict = {'cat' : cats,
                        'rabbits' : rabbits}
But my print statement is giving me this output: {'cat': ["Mary", "Snuggles", "Susan"], 'rabbits' : ["Cottonball", "Snowflake", "Fluffy"]}
However, I don't want the [] and {} symbols to be printed

Comment: @LiYe523 That is what dicts and lists look like when printed. Do you have any reason why you need different output?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the variables you already declared and make a dictionary:

```py
cats = ["Mary", "Snuggles", "Susan"]
rabbits = ["Cottonball", "Snowflake", "Fluffy"]

animals = {
  "cats": cats,
  "rabbits": rabbits
}
```

If you want to push more cats or rabbits to the list:

to add a cat:

```
cats.append('Bob')
```

to add a rabbit:

```
rabbit.append('John')
```

The nice thing is that although you changed the lists, these changes are reflected in the dict, because the dict references them.

to add a new key to the dict

```py
aniamls["dogs"] = ["Martin", ...]
```